# What is the maximum length of an openAM SSO token?

Tags: openam

I have found some configuration parameters which might affect the length, but nothing that really defines it. I have found some that are 94 characters and some that are 107.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to not rely on the length of the SSO token.

Future releases of OpenAM may change the token encoding (using a JWT, for example). You will want to make generous allowances for this.

Comment: That's great for everyone who isn't using C <s>